OpenMP parallel solving is slower than sequental
I am trying to do some math calculations in parallel and sequential processing to see the difference.
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

const int M = 100;
const int N = 100;

using namespace std;

int getRandomNum(int start, int end) {
  return rand() % (end - start + 1) + start;
}

int* parallelTask(int arr[M][N]) {
  int* answer = new int[M];
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp for
    // here is the same code as in sequentialTask
  }
}

int* sequentialTask(int arr[M][N]) {
  int* answer = new int[M];
  for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    int num = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      for (int k = 1; k < N - j; k++) {
        int mult = arr[i][j] * arr[i][j + k];
        bitset<32> bitset = mult;
        string mult_binary = bitset.to_string();
        for (int l = 0; l < mult_binary.size(); l++) {
          if (mult_binary[l] == '1') {
            num += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return answer;
}

void main() {
  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
  int arr[M][N];

  for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = getRandomNum(1, 10);
    }
  }

  double start;
  double end;

  start = omp_get_wtime();
  parallelTask(arr);
  end = omp_get_wtime();
  printf("Parallel work took %f seconds\n", end - start);

  start = omp_get_wtime();
  sequentialTask(arr);
  end = omp_get_wtime();
  printf("Regular work took %f seconds\n", end - start);
}

The problem is that the parallel work takes more time than sequential.
Parallel work took 2,314297 seconds
Regular work took 2,011105 seconds

I added num_threads(6) to #pragma omp parallel and there is the result:
Parallel work took 1,742959 seconds
Regular work took 2,010864 seconds

I have a 6-core processor and I think that the difference of using parallel processing must be bigger. There is my fault?

Parallelization in general and OpenMP in particular is not a magic "make it faster" button.  Sometimes a parallel version of an algorithm does run slower than a serial version, often because of high overhead and / or low true concurrency and / or memory locality effects.

With that said, after fixing a couple of unrelated (I think) errors, on my 6-core machine I do observe around a 6x speedup for the parallel computation in this program, relative to the serial computation.  Also a several times speedup of the serial vs your reported serial.  Did you maybe forget to compile with optimization enabled?

Tryed same code with num_threads(6) on another PC. Got this:
Parallel work took 1,776548 seconds Regular work took 5,118927 seconds
How is this explained?
And how to compile with optimization enabled?

Timing measurement is pointless if you compile without optimization.  On my machine, having compiled the program at optimization level -O2, I consistently get timings very close to Parallel work took 0.004611 seconds Regular work took 0.031151 seconds.  The difference between that and your result is far too great to attribute to my hardware vs yours.  I'm, still favoring my speculation that you're timing an un-optimized program.

are you compiling in release mode with optimizations enabled ? it takes like 3 milliseconds to solve with optimizations enabled https://godbolt.org/z/T9o3Pes99 , i think godbolt servers give you like 2 cores so you cannot trust its result too much in terms of timing

Note that I still get about the same timing when I modify the program to return and print the results of the computation, so that it cannot be optimized out.  Your numbers aren't even in the ballpark.  You must not be optimizing, in which case it is senseless to time the computation.

I changed Debug to Release and got
Parallel work took 0,015767 seconds Regular work took 0,110026 seconds
You were right, seems like compiler parameters were setted wrong

This code is very inefficient. You should try to optimize it before using multiple thread.  It basically counts ones which can be done with count. For 32-bit integers, this can be done with the instruction popcnt on mainstream x86-64 CPUs. This instruction usually takes 1 cycles (rcp-throughput). Meanwhile your code allocate a string, convert 32 bits to 32 char, parse them using a slow loop with an unpredictable condition before freeing the string. This is far more expensive than popcnt (at least 10x, possibly 100x slower).

On top of that, on recent CPUs supporting AVX-512, you can do this operation in a SIMD way thanks to the instruction vpopcntd. It can compute 16 integers/cycle. With that, you can make the sequential code >1000x faster without even using more thread!

Most compilers should be able to optimize out the inefficient algorithm in this function. None of the calculations have a side effect visible outside of the function. The compiler should just remove the whole for loop.

AFAICS the compiler cam completely remove all calculations, since there is no assignment to any members of the "answer" array...

@JérômeRichard Since C++20 there is also std::popcount() (taking any unsigned integral types) for writing portable code.

@Joachim While compilers can do that, no mainstream compiler actually do it. Removing allocations is difficult, and all functions needs to be inlined (otherwise they cannot do that). Compilers are far from being perfect/optimal. That being said, they do optimize out the loop if it is optimized (so to avoid allocations and a lot of useless code). See https://godbolt.org/z/jPzsqnneP .

@paleonix Good to know. In practice, count is portable and properly optimized by compilers (though popcount is more readable). Most are even able to generate the efficient vpopcntd AVX-512 instruction (assuming it is enabled properly which is generally not the case especially on Intel CPU due to this issue and AFAIK the same thing applies to GCC -- most people don't event set -march so compilers generate a code for 20-years old CPUs for sake of compatibility at the expense of bad performances).
